# How to draw an array of pixels from android native activity

Tags: android, c++

I'm using visual studio c++ to program a simple android app (native activity) to display a buffer of pixel. I've tried to draw the pixels with opengl 3.1 but it shows only a black screen (I'm a newbie with OpenGL ES)... So there's some way to draw the buffer every frame without a huge impact on performance?

That's a part of my code:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, buffer); //for initialization

/* other code */

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, buffer); //draw

eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
```

Comment: Do you mean OpenGL ES?

Comment: Yes opengl Es 3.1

Comment: OpenGL texture on a pair of triangles that make up a quadrilateral is the simplest answer.  Please note that _"...but it doesn't worked..."_ is not going to get you an answer to why it does not work. Please read [ask] with a [mcve].